# Unable to load PHPExcel library classes

Tags: php, phpexcel

Hi this is my current folder structure

/www/project1/   contains all php and html files
/www/project1/classes  contains all php classes with files named as class.Class1.php, class.Class2.php etc

My spl_autoloader function is as below

```
spl_autoload_register('classloader');
function classloader($class_name) {
        require_once 'classes/class.'.$class_name . '.php';    
}
```

in all my .php files i have used 
`require_once('autoload.php')` to load classes as required and it is working fine.

Now I am trying to use PHPExcel library to generate some excel files and I am getting errors like below

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'classes/class.PHPExcel.php' (include_path='clases/Classes/')

because all PHPExcel library files are named without 'class' in the beginning like my class files. I have copied all PHPExcel files in to my classes folder and there is an Autoloader.php inside Classes/PHPExcel folder.

How do I solve loading my classes along with that of PHPExcel library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using multiple autoloaders (in this case, both PHPExcel's and your own) then each autoloader should return a false if it can't include a class file. If an autoloader returns a false, then it will check with the next autoloader in the chain; if it doesn't return anything, then it will terminate execution of the autoloader chain.

Either ensure that the PHPExcel autoloader executes first, or modify your own autoloader to check for the existence of your own files before including them, and return a false if the requested class file doesn't exist so that it will then run PHPExcel's autoloader.

Comment: I modified my autoload function as below and it worked fine.   spl_autoload_register('classloader');
function classloader($class_name) {
 if(file_exists('classes/class.'.$class_name . '.php'))
 {
  require_once 'classes/class.'.$class_name . '.php';  
 }else{
  return false;
 }

}
Thank you